# Combine multiple swatch legends

Tags: graphics, legending

How can I combine multiple `SwatchLegend`s? As a minimal example:

```
Legended[
  Show[g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], Red, Sphere[]}]], 
    SwatchLegend[{Red, Red, Red}, {"x\[Rule]ξ", "y\[Rule]η", "z≡ζ"}]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[
  Show[g2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], Blue, Cylinder[]}]], 
    SwatchLegend[{Blue, Blue, Blue}, {"ξ≡ξ'", "η\[Rule]η'", "ζ\[Rule]ζ'"}]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[
  Show[g3 = Graphics3D[{Green, Cone[]}]], 
    SwatchLegend[{Green, Green, Green}, {"ξ'\[Rule]x'", "η'\[Rule]y'", "ζ'≡z'"}]]
```

[image]

Now I would like to combine them; something like

```
Legended[
  Show[{g1, g2, g3}], 
    SwatchLegend[{
      {Red, Red, Red}, {"x\[Rule]ξ", "y\[Rule]η", "z≡ζ"}, 
      {Blue, Blue, Blue}, {"ξ≡ξ'", "η\[Rule]η'", "ζ\[Rule]ζ'"}, 
      {Green, Green, Green}, {"ξ'\[Rule]x'", "η'\[Rule]y'", "ζ'≡z'"}}]]
```

[image]

does not work.

I failed to find a duplicate.

Comment: I don't understand. Have you tried to follow the syntax of `SwatchLegend`?

Comment: @Kuba: Do you mean that it just suffices to see the documentation of `SwatchLegend`?

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because I think it a bad idea to close an up-voted question with five good answers just because it is possible for a highly experienced _Mathematica_ user can work out a solution by reading the docs.

Comment: @m_goldberg sorry but I do not agree with your reopen reason. Could you elaborate why **only highly experienced users** are able to follow the syntax presented in usage section? I may have misssed something in this question, then Im sorry. But i really can't see a deeper bottom here. No I look like a bully ;)

Comment: P.s. but ofc I do not mind reopening, that's a part of this system

Comment: @Kuba. Perhaps "highly" is a bit hyper, but removing that word is the only change I would make to my comment if I could still edit it. OTOH I think at 20 years a user, I qualify as highly experienced, but I still find the documentation on legends rather opaque. I'm very glad that enough other _Mathematica_ agreed with me to get the question reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid redundant color swatches:

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], Red, Sphere[]}];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], Blue, Cylinder[]}];
g3 = Graphics3D[{Green, Cone[]}];

Legended[Show[g1, g2, g3],
 SwatchLegend[
  {Red, Blue, Green},
  {Column[{"", "x\[Rule]ξ", "y\[Rule]η", 
     "z≡ζ", ""}],
   Column[{"", "ξ≡ξ'", "η\[Rule]η'", 
     "ζ\[Rule]ζ'", ""}],
   Column[{"", "ξ'\[Rule]x'", "η'\[Rule]y'", 
     "ζ'≡z'", ""}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`Show` already combines these if you include the legends in your assignments.

```
x1 = Legended[Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], Red, Sphere[]}]], 
  SwatchLegend[{Red, Red, Red}, {"x\[Rule]ξ", "y\[Rule]η", "z≡ζ"}]];

x2 = Legended[Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], Blue, Cylinder[]}]], 
  SwatchLegend[{Blue, Blue, Blue}, {"ξ≡ξ'", "η\[Rule]η'", "ζ\[Rule]ζ'"}]];

x3 = Legended[Show[Graphics3D[{Green, Cone[]}]], 
  SwatchLegend[{Green, Green, Green}, {"ξ'\[Rule]x'", "η'\[Rule]y'", "ζ'≡z'"}]];
```

Now simply:

```
Show[x1, x2, x3]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

you can also do it like this:

```
Legended[Show[{g1, g2, g3}], 
 Grid[{SwatchLegend @@@ {{{Red, Red, Red}, {"x\[Rule]ξ", "y\[Rule]η", "z≡ζ"}}, 
  {{Blue, Blue, Blue}, {"ξ≡ξ'", "η\[Rule]η'", "ζ\[Rule]ζ'"}}, 
  {{Green, Green, Green}, {"ξ'\[Rule]x'", "η'\[Rule]y'", "ζ'≡z'"}}}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sure I would get many answers:-)!

Answer (score 8):

```
Legended[Show[{g1, g2, g3}], 
 SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
   RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}, 
  {"x\[Rule]ξ", "ξ≡ξ'", "ξ'\[Rule]x'", "y\[Rule]η", "η\[Rule]η'",  "η'\[Rule]y'", "z≡ζ", 
   "ζ\[Rule]ζ'", "ζ'≡z'"}, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 3}]]
```

[image: Row]

Or

```
Legended[Show[{g1, g2, g3}], 
 SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
    RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}, 
   {"x\[Rule]ξ", "ξ≡ξ'", "ξ'\[Rule]x'", "y\[Rule]η", "η\[Rule]η'", "η'\[Rule]y'", 
    "z≡ζ", "ζ\[Rule]ζ'", "ζ'≡z'"}, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Column", 3}]]
```

[image: Column]

Comment: Thanks a lot! All the answers I received are great!